# Effect of placing components under a magnetic component (transformer, inductor)

Tags: pcb, transformer, inductor, layout

I recently had my eyes on the the tear-down of onboard charger from Tesla, and saw that they have placed the control circuitry under the major magnetic components (PFC boost inductor (toroidal), phase-shifted full-bridge transformer). The control circuitry were placed on the other side of the PCB, but directly under these large magnetic components.

Wouldn't the magnetic field generated by, e.g. unshielded inductor, effects the control signal of the circuit? Or the shielding of the magnetic field with just a PCB enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the magnetics are closed loop toroids and not saturated, they won't leak much field. Magnetic effects from the current in the traces leading to those devices may be another story.

[image]

[Source](http://www.traftor.com/blog/ressource/toroidal-inductors-and-transformers-advantage-leakage-flux/)

Comment: does this mean that the traces that run on the same side of the PCB with those magnetics, still get effected by the magnetic field generated by leakage flux and distorted?

Comment: @NatthapolVanasrivilai no it means it depends on the geometry of the magnetics and what is driving them. If done properly, it does not matter where the traces are. If not, you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some math on HFI. If the vulnerable loop areas are small ---- 1mm X 10mm ---- and the dI/dT are slow ---500 amps in 100 nanoseconds, lets compute the injected Verror. We'll assume 0.1 volt is the threshold on Problem or Not a Problem. Let the distance be 1cm.

Verror (wire coupling into a loop, at some distance)

Verror = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

Verror = 2e-7 * 1mm * 10mm/10mm * 5,000 amps/microsecond

Verror = 2e-7 * 1e-3            *5000e^6 amp/second

Verror = 2e-10 * 5000e+6

Verror = 10,000 e-4 = ONE volts

Can your control circuitry tolerate 1 volt of feedback error?
Might the switching time-jitter get altered by this feedback? 
Should you care?